# Где хранятся ключи к алгоритму шифрования паролей Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, пароль, шифрование

Здравствуйте!

Где хранятся пароли, понятно (Login Data),  как их расшифровать и какими функциями, программно тоже понятно.

Интересует теоретическая сторона вопроса. 
Пароли зашифрованы алгоритмом AES с ключом длинны 256 бит.

Осталось два вопроса:

1. Где хранятся эти ключи? Директория, файл в системе?
2. DPAPI зависит от системы. Значит, теоретически, если попробовать дешифровать файл Login Data, то ничего не выйдет?

Comment: Хм. Исходники по идее открыты, так что можно подсмотреть в них. Хотя, конечно, это трудоёмкий процесс.

Поскольку сам Chrome может расшифровать пароли, находясь на системе, то и вы теоретически сможете.

Comment: В линуксе точно используется keyring (у меня используется seahorse). А он сохраняет свои данные в `~/.local/share/keyrings`.